# Selection sort in C. Why?

Tags: c, sorting, selection

This is simple code in C (selection sort):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ItemCount 10

int numbers[ItemCount] = {4,9,3,7,2,5,10,2,12,6};    

int MinNumberIndex(int start) {
    int i;
    int minindex = start;

    for (i = start + 1; i < ItemCount; i++)
        if (numbers[minindex] > numbers[i])
            minindex = i;

    return minindex;    
}


void SelectionSort() {
    int i,temp,minindex;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        minindex = MinNumberIndex(i);

        temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[minindex ];
        numbers[minindex ] = temp;                                                                          
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;

    SelectionSort();
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\t",  numbers[i]);

    system("pause");    
}
```

And it is working ok... but if I change a little bit like this(in selectionSort function):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    temp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[MinNumberIndex(i)];
    numbers[MinNumberIndex(i)] = temp;                                                                          
}
```

it is not working... Why? It seems to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by MinNumberIndex depends on the contents of the array. You're changing the content when you do:

```
numbers[i] = numbers[MinNumberIndex(i)];
```

so the next call:

```
numbers[MinNumberIndex(i)] = temp;
```

will/can store to the wrong cell since MinNumberIndex(i) can have changed. This breaks the algorithm because you're not doing a proper swap.

Answer (score 1):

Because `MinNumberIndex(i)` returns different values each time you call it, so the second version really isn't a value swap.

Answer (score 1):

Since `MinNumberIndex(i)` returns the index of the smallest element in the range `[i,ItemCount-1]` and your alternate version of the code modifies that range in the array between the two calls to `MinNumberIndex()`, you're not swapping elements.

Your alternate loop is eqivalent to:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        {

            temp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[MinNumberIndex(i)];
            numbers[i] = temp;                                                                          
        }
```

In a bit more detail, when this line of code is executed in the `for` loop:

```
numbers[i] = numbers[MinNumberIndex(i)];
```

It makes `numbers[i]` the minimum in the array range you're dealing with at that moment, so the next time `MinNumberIndex(i)` is called, it'll return `i`. And

```
numbers[i] = temp;
```

will just restore the array to the same state it was in at the top of the loop.